Closedness of maximal ideal in unital normed algebras
A classical result in the theory of Banach Algebra states that every maximal ideal in a commutative unital Banach algebra is closed. This generalizes to normed, possibly non-Banach algebras?
In other words, is it true that every maximal ideal in a commutative unital normed algebra is closed?

No. Let $P([0,1])$ be the commutative normed algebra of polynomials on $[0,1]$, equipped with the supremum norm. Then $1+x$ is not invertible in $P([0,1])$ as $(1+x)^{-1}$ is not a polynomial. Hence, there exists a maximal ideal $I$ containing $1+x$. I claim that $I$ cannot be closed. Indeed, by Stone-Weierstrass theorem, there exists a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ that conveges to $(1+x)^{-1}$ under the sup norm on $[0,1]$. But this means the sequence $(1+x)p_n\in I$ converges to $1$, so if $I$ is closed, we would have $1\in I$, a contradiction.

Also worth noting: the assumption of commutativity in the post is irrelevant. Every maximal ideal in a unital Banach algebra is closed, commutative or not.
